# MVC 5 Razor User.IsInRole("roleName") not using custom user store

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I have an Asp.Net 5 app using Identity 1.0, and I have implemented a custom user manager that provides custom logic specifically for User Roles.

All is working fine when I use the **Authorize** attribute on controllers/actions, however when I use **User.IsInRole(roleName)** on a Razor page, the custom logic is ignored and an incorrect value is returned.

I have searched for hours around this issue and cannot find any way to override the default behaviour of **User.IsInRole(...)**. Unless I am missing something I will have to write an extension method, but it seems ridiculous that an implementation of a custom user provider isn't actually used in some of the program!

---

**EDIT:** Custom User Store code. I am convinced this is correct as it is being executed correctly when used in conjunction with the **Authorize** attribute, however by setting a break point on the method I can confirm that it is not run when invoking **User.IsInRole(...)**

```
public class CustomUserStore :
    IUserStore<User, int>,
    IUserLoginStore<User, int>,
    IUserPasswordStore<User, int>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<User, int>,
    IUserEmailStore<User, int>,
    IUserLockoutStore<User, int>,
    IUserTwoFactorStore<User, int>,
    IUserPhoneNumberStore<User, int>,
    IUserClaimStore<User, int>,
    IUserRoleStore<User, int>,
    IQueryableUserStore<User, int>,
    IDisposable
{

    // ...

    public async Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roleName));

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // using Dapper.Net extension methods
            var role = await con.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<Role>("select * from Roles where Name = @roleName", new { roleName });
            if (role == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Role {roleName} doesn't exist");

            // calling this stored procedure directly on Sql Server yields expected results
            var results = await con.QueryAsync("IsUserInRole", new { userId = user.Id, roleId = role.Id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return results.Count() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
This is the code to create the Identity Principal:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: (user) => user.GetUserId<int>())
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);            
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
}
```

Comment: a) update to Identity v2 - it is much better. b) show your custom user manager with the custom logic. I'm not sure about v1, but in v2 `User.IsInRole` is checking the cookie and if the cookie knows about this role. Are your roles added to the cookie?

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with v1 for the time being. I have added my custom logic. Yes I am using cookie authentication. Thanks

Comment: Show your login code? where you crate a claims identity and claims principal?

Comment: I have not explicitly created a claims identity or claims principle, do you have any links on how to do this?

Comment: Well, how do you login your users? I have links, but all of them are for v2